# Android layout coming out of screen in layout preview

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

I'm working on a small project and all of a sudden layout preview has started misbehaving.Its coming out of the screen. Its not the case with layout height or width!! You can get clear picture with these images

[image: This is the first image]

This is the second image :

[image: second image]

It is very clear that the blue color border is coming out of screen.

I've found this question in SO but it is not related to my question.

[stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099578/elements-out-of-screen-in-android-layout)

These are the things I tried

1. Clean and Make project haven't worked
2. Rebuilding project haven't worked
3. Invalidate cache and restart Android Studio too haven't worked :/

This is the xml code of activity_details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="bk.photoorganizer.DetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/photos_rec_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the xml code of activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="bk.photoorganizer.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tabText"
            app:tabTextColor="#63FFFFFF"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: post the xml code, it will be good idea.

Comment: sure please wait a sec..

Comment: @bharath Use RelativeLayout instead of  CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: Actually the problem is not with layout. It worked well with coordinator layout and when I switched on laptop again from sleep its misbehaving

Comment: Try and exit android studio and open it again.

Comment: I think invalidating cache is same ?

Comment: @bharath Atleast once please try to replace RelativeLayout with CoordinatorLayout because same this happens with my code as well and i did the same.

Comment: Android studios preview is not accurate, always test on a phisical device. Just try to exit and open again.

Comment: exited android studio still no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution to control your view appearance :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                >
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbar">
        <include layout="@layout/list_elec"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Included Layout should be **FrameLayout**:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/photos_rec_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks brother that helped me !!